# When using RMarkdown, is there a way to insert images (png), knit and generate and html file that I can email and still show the images?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Disclaimer: Ok, I am somewhat new to R, so I am not an expert at all. I have spent 2 hours searching the following, thinking it would be a simple search. But it hasn't. I want to insert png images in a R Markdown file that I will knit into an HTML file so that I can email it. I see that I can include the image in a chunk, and even see it in the output HTML file after knitting without problem by including the following code:

```
{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="A caption", out.width = '50%'}
knitr::include_graphics("OutputMARSParameters.png")
```

But, unless I create a zip file with all the png files + the html file used in the R Markdown file, those images will not show in the html the other person receives from me. Is there a way to do this so that I don't have to email all the images as well, but just one html file that would have all images somehow in it, i.e. an emailable single html with all images rendered in it?

Comment: By default, the document produced should be a self-contained HTML file. Make sure that you don't have `self_contained: false` in the YAML document metadata. Have you confirmed that the images don't show if you don't include the PNG files along with your HTML?

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you knit the HTML file, it should have created a standalone document, unless you've added `self_contained: false` in the YAML document metadata.

Here's a simple R markdown file that I created with the default settings:

````
---
title: "Demo"
author: "A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1"
date: "7/14/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Including External Graphic

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="A caption", out.width = '50%'}
knitr::include_graphics("html-file-with-code-symbol.png")
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk 
to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

You can see the final HTML [at this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/c4dbdf122808067e14c5f29c18a36322) and see what that renders as [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mrdwab/raw/c4dbdf122808067e14c5f29c18a36322/).

The interesting/relevant portion starts [at line 522](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/c4dbdf122808067e14c5f29c18a36322#file-index-html-L522) in this file. Notice that it doesn't refer to the image file as the `src`, but rather, it starts `<img src="data:image/png;base64,....`. The long string of text in the `....` is the base64 string representing your image. In fact, you can copy the text content in the `src` tag and paste it into [a base64 converter](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image) to see the image as well.

If you want to verify you've done things correctly, just try temporarily renaming one of the pngs you've included in your document. If it still displays in your HTML output, you should be good to go.